# Finding 4D Volumes using Numerical Integration

Tags: numerical-integration, geometry

I am trying to integrate

```
    Integrate[

     Boole[Sqrt[X^2 + Y^2] + Sqrt[(X - x)^2 + (Y - y)^2] + 
        Sqrt[(2.5 - x)^2 + y^2] < 2.6],

 {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity},
 {X, -Infinity, Infinity}, {Y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

which should give the volume of the 4D Euclidean plane where a "three-hop path" starting at $(0,0)$, and ending at $(2.5,0)$ is less than 2.6 units in length (its minimum length is 2.5, since this is the straight line).

The 4D plane is the product space of a pair of 2D coordinates (the vertices on the path).

Mathematica can't seem to evaluate it. Is there something wrong? I've tried removing one of the variables to get a partial form of the integral in a special case, and that works....any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some manual effort to tighten the bounds on the domain as much as possible,
and using monte carlo:

```
NIntegrate[
 Boole[Sqrt[X^2 + Y^2] + Sqrt[(X - x)^2 + (Y - y)^2] + 
    Sqrt[(25/10 - x)^2 + y^2] < 26/10],
    {x, 0, 26/10},
    {y, -Sqrt[51]/20, Sqrt[51]/20},
    {X, -1/20, 26/10},
    {Y, -Sqrt[51]/20, Sqrt[51]/20}, 
    Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo", WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

> 0.65291001515151360000

I think this is only good to 2 decimal places. You can increase `PrecisionGoal` , etc to improve.

Comment: Thank you. Is there some reason why Mathematica only manages to find this only after some work with the integration limits?

Comment: I don't know. Its a nice smooth surface, I think it shouldn't be so difficult.

Answer (score 1):

```
NIntegrate[
 Boole[
       Sqrt[xx^2 + yy^2] + 
       Sqrt[(xx - x)^2 + (yy - y)^2] + 
       Sqrt[(2.5 - x)^2 + y^2] < 2.6], 
  {x, -10, 10}, 
  {y, -10, 10}, 
  {xx, -10, 10}, 
  {yy, -10, 10}]
```

(*

0.256576

*)

Comment: So basically I need to use NIntegrate. I was somehow under the impression that Integrate would know it was meant to be numerical.

Comment: No.  Integrate is a *symbolic* function, which would apply to `Integrate[Sin[x], {x, a,b}]`, for instance.  Even if the limits and such are given numerically, *Mathematica* tries to solve the integral symbolically and then plugs in the values of the given variables.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Comment: Use with caution, this throws convergence warning and gives quite different results if you change the integration limits.

Comment: Why does it give slow convergence on this?

Comment: It takes 11.7 seconds on my Mac desktop (v. 10.4.0.0).

Comment: Thank you again.