# Configuration integral for a variable number of points on a torus

Tags: numerical-integration, computational-geometry, combinatorics

If I have $n$ points on the surface of a torus, and want to check the Euclidean length of all "three-hop paths" between two (newly added) fixed points $s,t$ at distance $||s-t||$ apart, I need to check the sum of the edge lengths over $ 2 {n \choose 2}$ paths.

With $n=3$ there are 6 paths I can form. With $n=4$, there are 12.

Using `Boole`, I can determine if any of these path lengths are shorter than some critical value, e.g. for $(x,y)$ and $(X,Y)$ two points in the plane....

```
Boole[Sqrt[X^2 + Y^2] + Sqrt[(X - x)^2 + (Y - y)^2] + 
   Sqrt[(d - x)^2 + y^2] < L]
```

returns 1 whenever the three-hop path is shorter than a length $L$, with $||s-t||=d$, and zero otherwise.

With three points, as mentioned, there are six routes. I would need six instances of `Boole` like the one above, each in 4 variables, in order to check all the paths to see if any were shorter than $L$.

I could then integrate these functions over all configurations of 3 points, to see what proportion of all configurations have a path of length less than $L$, for example.

**Is there a way to write a function which takes in $n$, a natural number, and returns the `Boole` as above for me, with each of the lengths used in inclusive OR?** So the above equation would be returned when $n=2$. With $n=3$, it would have $6$ separate conditions, any one of which returning true gives this `Boole` function the value 1, and is otherwise zero.

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164590/finding-4d-volumes-using-numerical-integration

Comment: Yes, also the paths a three “hops” long

Comment: I need to set up a numerical integral which gives the CDF of the length of the shortest path s —> t via two other nodes

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, given $n$ points, you'd like a function `fun[s, t, L]` that would return the proportion of 3-hop paths that are shorter than $L$ among all 3-hop paths. Then, you would integrate `fun` over `s` and `t`. This brute-force approach might be time-consuming...

Comment: Yes. But is it possible to do? If it worked only for small n that would be fine

Comment: A naive approach for the function `fun` might be slow, but will certainly work. I'll give a try if I find the time (not sure). In the meanwhile, maybe you could simplify a bit the question (including the title) to make it a bit more attractive. For example the torus part is not really relevant. I'm pretty sure some gurus would have fun with this question.

Comment: The torus is to indicate the domain has no boundary, but I’ll try and simplify it.

Comment: Are s and t just numbers referring to the positions of those points in pts?

Comment: r = 1;
n = 100;
pts = Table[{RandomReal[{-r, r}], RandomReal[{-r, r}]}, {k, 1, n}];
pts = Append[pts, {-r/2, 0}];
pts = Append[pts, {r/2, 0}];
ratio[s_, t_, l_] := 
 Block[{}, paths = {s}~Join~#~Join~{t} & /@ Subsets[pts, {2}]; 
  lengths = Total[Norm /@ Differences[#]] & /@ paths; 
  1 - .5*Total[Sign[lengths - l] + 1]/Length@lengths]
ratio[201, 202, r + 3]

Comment: So ... ratio[{-1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0}, r + 3] would give the proportion of paths less than 3 greater than the maximum (which is r, the norm of s-t).

Comment: You probably mean _minimum_. If so, yes (well, don't forget to check `:)` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function `ratio` takes two points `s` and `t`, the list of $n$ points `pts`, and it returns the ratio of lengths shorter than `length`. It runs in 2ms for `n=50` which is reasonable.

```
n = 50;
length = 4;
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
s = {-1, 1}; t = -s;

ratio[s_, t_, l_] := Block[{},
  paths = {s}~Join~#~Join~{t} & /@ Subsets[pts, {2}];
  lengths = Total[Norm /@ Differences[#]] & /@ paths;
  1 - .5*Total[Sign[lengths - l] + 1]/Length@lengths]
```

To be used as `ratio[s,t,length]`.

For example you can plot `ratio` for `t` at the origin and `s` integrated along the $x$ axis:

```
Plot[ratio[{x, 0}, {0, 0}, length], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

**Regarding your comment** You want a function to return 1 if the shortest of all three-hop paths is shorter than $l$. Given that $n$ is finite, you could simply use `If[ratio[s,t,l]==0, 1, 0]`. The following function should also work (I did not test it):

```
shortQ[s_, t_, l_] := Block[{},
  paths = {s}~Join~#~Join~{t} & /@ Subsets[pts, {2}];
  lengths = Total[Norm /@ Differences[#]] & /@ paths;
  If[Min[lengths] <= l, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: So it looks at all paths of three hops from s to t, and gives the proportion of them less than l in Euclidean length.

Comment: Correct. Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes indeed. What I would like to do is numerically integrate this over general $d$-dimensional point configurations, so over an $nd$-dimensional integral. This should give the CDF of the path count less than l in length.

Comment: This works nicely. Thank you for such a quick response.

Comment: Can this potentially be modified to give a true/false output (0/1) whenever the shortest of all the three-hop paths (the "geodesic" path) is less than L?

Comment: Ok that is nice. This gives me a better shot at the CDF of the geodesic length.